# How to use SQL CASE for user id count up to 5 and display data in column.?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

In word-press I am joining 3 tables users, user_meta and one custom table student.
Here in student custom table am having maximum 5 student and student data is storing according to user id.  So i am trying to retrieve all student as per userid in a single query.
See what I have tried:

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    COUNT(u.id) as child_count,
    u.display_name,
    u.user_email AS login,
    u.user_nicename AS u_name,
    u.user_registered AS reg_on,
    m1.meta_value AS parent_fname,
    m2.meta_value AS parent_fname,
    s.firstname as child_fname,
    s.lastname as child_lname,
    s.year_group as child_age,
    s.subjects as child_int_sub
FROM wp_users u
JOIN wp_usermeta m1 ON (m1.user_id = u.id AND m1.meta_key = 'billing_first_name')
JOIN wp_usermeta m2 ON (m2.user_id = u.id AND m2.meta_key = 'billing_last_name')
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta m3 ON (m3.user_id = u.id AND m3.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' AND m3.meta_value LIKE '%subscriber%')
JOIN wp_student_table s ON (s.parent_id = u.ID)
GROUP BY s.id;
```

and if I run this query in phpmyadmin

[image]

So how I can use case for

userid count = 1 then column(child1_name,child1_age )
userid count = 2 then column(child2_name,child1_age )
and so on..

to show all child of same user in single row.

Comment: The query is malformed. MySQL 5.7 and older used to accept those types of queries. Please include a few rows of sample data and your expected result.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask